# Setting a countdown timer and having problems with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've set up a countdown timer with 1 sec interval and increment / decrement in mill secs..

I then searched for something that would give me the value in minutes/seconds. I came up with the following:

```
var timer = 130000;
var mins = Math.floor((timer % 36e5) / 6e4),
    secs = Math.floor((timer % 6e4) / 1000);
```

The above code works on Safari, Chrome and Firefox with no problem.  When I get to Internet Explorer, it doesn't work at all.

Is there another way of doing it that would work on all browsers?

Comment: Have you tried not using exponential notation?

Comment: I did not write the above my self, i found it somewhere on the net, and i am unfamiliar with exponential notation

Comment: I cleaned up your post.  Please take the time to use proper spelling, punctuation and grammar when you expect others to take the time to help.

Comment: Thank you very much. i will try and make sure things i posts from now on will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing the exponetial.

```
var timer = 130000;
var mins = Math.floor((timer % 3600000) / 60000),
    secs = Math.floor((timer % 60000) / 1000);
```

Read more about ***[Exponential Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)***.

An Exponential Notation if number with format `a x 10^n`, where `1<= a < 10` and `n` is integer with positive or negative value.

For example:

```
36e5
= 36 x 10^5
= 36 x 100000
= 3600000
```

ans so on.

Comment: I've tested the above. it doesn't seem to work. maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Then please tell us exactly how it's not working. Your problem might well be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I've found the problem. it had nothing to do with what i thought it was it is $j("#title").text( secs + ' Secs'); which try to change the text of <title></title> i was sure IE can do that guess not.